# Regex which matches any subdomain

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for Regex, which will match any URL, which starts with "http" or "https" and contains specific domain. If the domain is "stackoverflow.com" I should be able to extract all domain and subdomain matches from a string (the .com only, so .net, .org etc. should not be matched) and then add them to a list by looping through all matches. How do I do that?

So far, this is the best workaround I have found (searching a string called "somestring" and adding the results to a list "myList")

```
       Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<Protocol>\w+):\/\/(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)\/?[\w\.?=%&=\-@/$,]*");
       Match m = r.Match(somestring);
       while (m.Success) 
       {
           if ((m.Value).Contains("stackoverflow.com"))
           {
           myList.Add(m.Value);
           }
        m = m.NextMatch();
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean - you want to test whether a url is to a page on stackoverflow.com or any of its subdomains (eg. m.stackoverflow.com )?

How about parsing the URL

```
new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827755/regex-which-matches-any-subdomain").Host
```

Then test whether the Host property ends with '.stackoverflow.com' or equals 'stackoverflow.com' exactly.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Comment: Colonel Panic, I want to extract all matches from a string - if the string is "http://www.http://stackoverflow.comaaaaa kkkkhttp://moo.stackoverflow.comlll ggggghttp://www.something.stackoverflow.comggggg" I want to extract "http:// stackoverflow.com" "http:// moo.stackoverflow.com" and "http:// www.something.stackoverflow.com" and add them to my list. The string could contain return carriages and new lines as well. The solution that I have posted in my (updated) question does exactly that, but causes huge performance problems. Hope this makes it somewhat clear

Comment: another example - if I save the source of this webpage as a string, I want to extract every single valid URL (which starts with http or https) and contains "stackoverflow.com" and save it to my list. Keep im mind that "stackoverflow.com" is just an example, it could be any domain name such as "google.com" "moo.net" etc. Thank you all that are trying to help

Answer (score 1):

This might give you a start on what to do:

`https?://(www\.)?([^.]+)\.([^.]+.)+`

Explanation:

`https?://`

Matches http or https.

`(www\.)?`

If www. is present, matches it.

`([^\s.]+)`

Matches the website's name (which consists of one or more non-dot non-whitespace characters).

`(\.[^\s.]+)+`

Matches one or more domains/subdomains (which consist of a dot, then one or more non-dot non-whitespace characters).

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can figure it out and once I do, I will post back